# Unable to get 2 LEDs working. [Raspberry pi, bare metal]

Tags: c, embedded, raspberry-pi, bare-metal

I am facing an issue in getting 2 LEDs glow one after another or at the same time. However, they work separately only one at a time. The problem comes when I try to achieve this in the same program. Only the first LED starts filckering not the other one.
Following is my code:

```
#define GPFSEL1 0x20200004
#define GPFSEL2 0x20200008

#define GPSET0  0x2020001C
#define GPCLR0  0x20200028

#define SET_PIN18_OUTPUT (0x01 << 24) // GPFSEL1
#define SET_PIN23_OUTPUT (0x01 << 9)  // GPFSEL2
#define SET_PIN24_OUTPUT (0x01 << 12) // GPFSEL2

#define SET_GPION(x)   (0x01 << x)
#define CLEAR_GPION(x) (0x01 << x)

#define NUM_OF_LEDS 3

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef unsigned int* UINT32_P;

void dummy(volatile unsigned int val)
{
  val++;
}

void setBit(unsigned int regAdd, unsigned char bit)
{
  unsigned int temp;
  temp  = *(UINT32_P)(regAdd);
  temp  |= (0x1 << bit);
  *(UINT32_P)(regAdd) = temp;
}

void clearBit(unsigned int regAdd, unsigned char bit)
{
  unsigned int temp;
  temp = *(UINT32_P)(regAdd);
  temp &= ~(1 << bit);
  *(UINT32_P)(regAdd) = temp;
}

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;

    setBit(GPFSEL1, 24);  // Configure PIN 18 to output
    setBit(GPFSEL2, 12);  // Configure PIN 24 to output
    while(1)
    {
    // L1 - -
    setBit(GPSET0, 18);
    setBit(GPSET0, 24);
    for(ra=0;ra<0x100000;ra++) dummy(ra);


    // - L2 -
    setBit(GPCLR0, 18);
    setBit(GPCLR0, 24);
    for(ra=0;ra<0x100000;ra++) dummy(ra);

    for(ra=0;ra<0x100000;ra++) dummy(ra);



    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You would do well to remove the unused redundant macros from this code - that is just a distraction to anyone who might be able to help you.

Comment: Style fixes: use uint32_t from stdint.h (C99), #define SET_GPION(x) (0x01 << (x)) (and unused), registers should be volatile to avoid compiler optimization

Answer (score 4):

The GPIO peripheral has separate registers for setting (`GPSET0`) and clearing (`GPCLR0`) output pins so that you don't have to do read-modify-write operations.  Writing to the GPSET register only sets the bits that are 1 while the bits that are 0 remain unchanged.  And writing to the GPCLR register only clears the bits that are 1 while the bits that are 0 remain unchanged.

You should not be using your `setBit()` and `clearBit()` routines for setting and clearing GPIO outputs.  Those routines might be appropriate for other peripherals that don't have separate registers for setting and clearing bits.  But the read-modify-write operation is not appropriate for `GPSET0` and `GPCLR0`.  In fact the read-modify-write operation may actually be the source of your problem.  It may be that `GPSET0` and `GPCLR0` always return 0x00000000 when you read them because it should never be necessary to read them.  (I'm not sure of that, I'm just speculating.)

Instead of calling `setBit()` and `clearBit()` to set the GPIO outputs you should just write to `GPSET0` or `GPCLR0` directly.  You don't need to read `GPSET0` or `GPCLR0` before writing to them.  Because when you write to them, only the bits you set to 1 will change, the bits that you write to 0 will remain unchanged.

Try something like this:

```
// Set bits
*(UINT32_P)GPSET0 = (1 << 18);
*(UINT32_P)GPSET0 = (1 << 24);

// Clear bits
*(UINT32_P)GPCLR0 = (1 << 18);
*(UINT32_P)GPCLR0 = (1 << 24);
```

Comment: Good spot, though in fact he is calling only setBit with the different addresses GPSET0  and GPCLR0, so it is read read-modify-write operation that is unnecessary.  So far my suggestion that he remove the unused code to clarify the question has been ignored.

Answer (score 1):

In `notmain()` you never call `clearBit()`, only `setBit()`.

The type:

```
typedef unsigned int* UINT32_P;
```

should be declared:

```
typedef volatile unsigned int* UINT32_P;
```

I would suggest defining your addresses as pointers rather than integers:

```
#define GPFSEL1 ((UINT32_P)0x20200004)
#define GPFSEL2 ((UINT32_P)0x20200008)

#define GPSET0  ((UINT32_P)0x2020001C)
#define GPCLR0  ((UINT32_P)0x20200028)
```

With set/clearBit taking a UINT32_P rather than an unsigned int. Then you won't need numerous casts.

The [BCM2835](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) includes timer hardware that you would do better to utilise than "busy-loops".

Answer (score 0):

Each GPIO pin has 3 bits to select a function. You only set one of the three bits, the lowest, while leaving the upper two bits alone. So my guess is that at boot pin 18 has function 0 and pin 24 has function 2 (or so). You then configure pin 18 to function 1, so it works, but pin 24 to function 3, which does not.

You should write a function "void setFunction(uint32_t pin, uint32_t fn)" that, depending on pin, loads one of GPFSEL0/GPFSEL1/GPFSEL2, masks out the 3 bits for the specified pin, ors in the 3 bits specified in fn and finally writes it back to the register.

The other thing I spot, which was already mentioned above, is that GPSET0/GPCLR0 don't need a read-modify-write. Just write the bit you want to set/clear to them directly. It won't affect any other bits.